# Can see other computers in Homegroup and their libraries, but nothing happens when I click them

Tags: windows-7, homegroup

I created a Homegroup for the 3 PC's in our home running W7. The problem is that all 3 PC's are in the Homegroup and I can see eachother, but when I try to click on the shared library on either of the computers that didn't create the Homegroup, nothing happens. I can see the shared libraries (Pictures, Music etc.), but it simply does nothing when I click on it. However, I am able to access (both ways) to and from the computer that created the Homegroup from the other 2 joiners.

Here is a illustration I made to make it easier to understand what I am saying:

[image]

The green double arrows indicate that access works both ways. The grey double arrow shows that they can see each other in the Homegroup, and can see their shared libraries, but nothing happens when you double-click that shared library.

I triple checked that all the PC's have identical sharing settings. I also double-checked that the firewall is not the source of the problem because I completely shut them off to test, still no change. I use Kaspersky Internet Security 2012 on two of the PC's,and Comodo Internet Security on the third PC.

I don't know what else to try.

Comment: If you open Windows Explorer, go to Network and try to access their shared folders and libraries - does it work?

Answer (score 1):

The security setting on all PCs should be set for "everyone" (this setting is necessary)

Also, check again that file and print sharing is enabled.

All should have the same homegroup "Name".